# Mashup Data Source Error when using Date field columns in DirectQuery mode

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've nearly 10 visuals in canvas, and the report is running under Snowflake Datawarehouse in DirectQuery mode. Few visuals have date parameter as their coordinates or in filter everything is working as anticipated in PowerBI Desktop version, but after publishing same to PowerBI service things got broken, All visuals with date columns (in filter or coordinates) not render with title error.

> Cannot connect to the mashup data source. see error details for information.

Clicking error details shows following error

```
Couldn't retrieve the data for this visual. Please try again later.
Please try again later or contact support. If you contact support, please provide these details.
```

I previously read and understand that DirectQuery mode will not consider or apply Date and Time intelligence to date fields, that is ok but nowhere mentioned that Visuals with date fields will not work.

How to get Reports back now?

Comment: Hi Ashok, how can you setup the Snowflake's ODBC connection via their driver (via ODBC Settings) to use the DirectQuery ? thanks!

Comment: Using Direct Query is upto Driver, you need to set up Query mode while adding datasource in PowerBI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall either On-premise or Enterprise gateway from the Power BI server and try again.

Comment: updated enterprise gateway (by September 2018) fixed this issue.